# IPv6 são vulneraveis a ataques DDoS?

Tags: redes, proteção, ddos

Existe como atacar um endereço IPV6 utilizando `DDoS`, isto é, inundar o trafego de um servidor que utiliza `IPv6`?

Exemplo: WebSite.com [xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx::x], gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de derrubar websites que não possuem protocolo `IPv4` somente `IPv6`.

Estava pensando em talvez utilizar somente `IPv6` nos meus servidores em quesito de segurança.

Comment: Se está online, está passivel de ataque, independente do protocolo utilizado.

Comment: Não encontrei nada a respeito sobre DDoS em WebSites IPV6, então pensei que não tinha como :C

Comment: Uma simples pesquisa no Google me retornou umas coisas interessantes, dá uma olhada: http://fenainfo.org.br/info_ler.php?id=40215

Comment: Sim, eu tambem encontrei isso, mas creio que se refira a rede interna [LAN]. e estou me referindo a WAN [IP Dedicado]. Pois já encontrei varias ferramentas para inundação ddos em redes IPv6 [Somente interna]

Comment: E por que não seria? Não encontrou nada porque não são assuntos relacionados.

Comment: Não existe relação, sua aplicação vai continuar suscetível aos mesmos problemas uma vez que independente do protocolo de "identificação" o servidor persistem idêntico.

Answer (score 0):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas vamos lá!

IPv6 nada mais é do que o IPv4 com uma quantidade de 128 bits, em resumo.
Ele inclui letras, números e resolve nossa demanda atual por endereços de IPs.

Um servidor APENAS sob IPv6, pode diminuir um ataque DDoS, já que somente os IPv6 irão acessa-lo, mas não significa que seja imune.
Administro um servidor de hospedagem que hospeda alguns sites grandes e já recebemos ataques DDoS que incluíam tanto IPv4 quanto IPv6. Ter um ou outro desativado só vai diminuir a gama de IPs que acessariam seu servidor.

E não recomendo que você desative o IPv4, especialmente no Brasil, muitas operadoras ainda não aderiram o IPv6 em todos os estados ou atualizaram seus roteadores, a maioria dos acessos ainda são por IPv4.